# How can I show the units on the labels of the ordinate axis, not just numbers?

Tags: plotting, labeling, time-series

I have a `DateListStepPlot`. The abscissa is meaningfully labeled. However, on the ordinate axis, the labels just show numbers. But I want to show their unit too (e.g. °C or € or whatsoever).

**How can I achieve this?** There will be an option to add such labels to the labels, I guess.

**Which is the right one and can do I have to use it?**

For example:

`li2={{DateObject[{2022, 3, 7}, "Day", "Gregorian", "Europe/Berlin"],  6858.76}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 8}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  20294.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 9}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  29719.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 10}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  36544.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 11}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  39694.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 12}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  41344.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 13}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  44794.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 14}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  45894.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 15}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  47319.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 16}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  47619.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 17}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  48839.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 18}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  49739.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 19}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  50339.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 20}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  50439.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 21}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  50489.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 22}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  50694.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 23}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  51454.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 25}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  51634.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 26}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  52634.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 28}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  52984.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  53234.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  54434.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 3, 31}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  55134.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 4, 3}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  56134.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 4, 4}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  56294.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 4, 5}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  56844.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 4, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"],  57364.8}, {DateObject[{2022, 4, 8}, "Day", "Gregorian",  "Europe/Berlin"], 57364.8}}; DateListStepPlot[li2, PlotRange->All, AxesLabel->{"€",""}, PlotLabel->"Fundraising"]`

Strangely the AxesLabel are not shown (why)? But **I would prefer the € sign directly following the € amounts on the ordinate axe's labels.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example:

```
data = {Quantity[10, "Millibars"], Quantity[12, "Millibars"], 
  Quantity[14, "Millibars"], Quantity[18, "Millibars"], 
  Quantity[20, "Millibars"]}

dates = {DateObject[{2022, 1, 1}], Automatic, "Month"}

DateListStepPlot[data, dates
 , FrameLabel -> Automatic
 , FrameTicks -> {
   {Automatic
    , {#, Quantity[#, "Millibars"]} & /@ Range[0, 20, 5]
    }
   , {Automatic, None}
   }]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT - to include OP's particular use case**

Let `data` be the data:

```
DateListStepPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> Automatic
 , FrameTicks -> {
   {{#, Quantity[NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3], "Euros"]} & /@ 
     Range[0, Round[First@Max[alist], 10000], 10000]
    , Automatic}
   , {Automatic, None}
   }
 , PlotLabel -> "Fundraising"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the accept.